# Is it possible to have a variable in the title of an Automator Service file?

Tags: macos, services

When one right-clicks selected text on a Mac, one is presented with various contextual menu items.  You may notice that some of the item titles contain the selected text.

For example, the Dictionary.app shortcut:

> Look Up "*selected text*"

Can this level of title adaptability be replicated with a Service created by Automator.app? Or are Service titles completely fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filename given in the "Save service as:" sheet, to the saved Automator Service, is what will appear on the Services context menu, sans the file extension.  It is fixed, sans renaming it, and cannot be a dynamic name automatically, as no mechanism is provided for it in a user made Automator Service.